# Connecting to oracle database using C programming

Tags: occi

I am trying to connect to oracle database using C code. Is it possible to use OCCI in the code? If yes please help me with some examples, please note it has to be C code.

If not what are the other options to connect to database using C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OCCI is short for 'Oracle C++ Call Interface' and is targeted to C++ applications. If your application is going to be purely in C, then you should use OCI (Oracle Call Interface) instead as that is Oracle's call interface for applications written in C.

See the [Programmer's guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/toc.htm) for help and examples.